# How to store foreach loop data into another Model?

Tags: php

I want to store my foreach loop data into another variable. The problem is that I can store data into database but when I dd() the output it only shows the last data assigned to the model.

How do I get the the array data from the new model?

```
foreach ($carts as $cart)
{
    $buy = new Buy();               
    $buy->product_id = $cart->product_id;
    $buy->user_id = $cart->user_id;
    $buy->price = $cart->price;
    $buy->extened = $cart->extened;
    $buy->installation = $cart->installation;
    $buy->support = $cart->support;             
    $buy->feature_image = $cart->feature_image;
    $buy->name = $cart->name;
    $buy->save();               
}

dd($buy);  // it returns only last inserted data ..
```

Comment: The `dd($buy);` is outside of the loop. So it only contains the last element. Move it inside the loop and it shows all.

Comment: Nope, only last element is showing

Comment: Since `dd()` means "dump and die" (it will literally stop the execution of the script when it's called), having that inside the loop will stop the script after the first iteration. You need to do a `print_r($buy)` or a `var_dump($buy)` inside the loop, if you want each item to be dumped to the screen. And then add an `exit;` after the loop, if you don't want to continue the script after...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, you will get the latest inserted data. Use the following code to get all the inserted Data. It is because at last execution of the `foreach` loop, `$buy` will have the latest `$cart` info.

You can use the following code to get all the `Buy` models. We are going to create an empty array and add `$buy` into the array.

```
$buys = array(); // I don't care about the name of the array lol.
foreach ($carts as $cart)
{
    $buy = new Buy();               
    $buy->product_id = $cart->product_id;
    $buy->user_id = $cart->user_id;
    $buy->price = $cart->price;
    $buy->extened = $cart->extened;
    $buy->installation = $cart->installation;
    $buy->support = $cart->support;             
    $buy->feature_image = $cart->feature_image;
    $buy->name = $cart->name;
    $buy->save();

    array_push($buys,$buy);        
}
```

It will store every record in `$buys` array and then you can do whatever you want to do with that array.

Let me know if this is what you wanted. Let me know if you have any more questions.

**UPDATE**: You can run `foreach` loop on `$buys` to display/update/delete  entries.